# Why C++ STL containers use "less than" operator< and not "equal equal" operator== as comparator?

Tags: c++, dictionary, operator-overloading, comparator

While implementing a comparator operator inside a custom class for `std::map`, I came across this question and couldn't see anywhere being asked.

Apart from the above question, also interested to know in brief, how `operator<` would work for `std::map`.

Origin of the question:

```
struct Address {
  long m_IPv4Address;
  bool isTCP;
  bool operator< (const Address&) const;  // trouble
};
```

Comment: If `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` then `(a == b)`.

Comment: if you know how to compare with `<` then everything else can be generated. check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23388739/4224575)

Comment: @jrok: Not necessarily. They're equivalent with respect to the ordering, but only equal if the definition of `operator==` agrees.

Comment: Well, yes. But that's what ordered containesr use, no?

Comment: @jrok: They use equivalence, not equality. The two concepts don't necessarily mean the same thing.

Comment: @RSahu I disagree, that [linked post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308437/why-use-stdless-as-the-default-functor-to-compare-keys-in-stdmap-and-stdse) did not have answers that answer the OP's question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::map<K,D>` needs to be able to sort.  By default is uses `std::less<K>`, which for non-pointers uses `<`<sup>1</sup>.

Using the rule that you demand the least you can from your users, it synthesizes "equivalence" from `<` when it needs it (`!(a<b) && !(b<a)` means `a` and `b` are equivalent, ie, neither is less than the other).

This makes it easier to write classes to use as key components for a `map`, which seems like a good idea.

There are `std` containers that use `==` such as `std::unordered_map`, which uses `std::hash` and `==`.  Again, they are designed so that they require the least from their users -- you don't need full ordering for `unordered_` containers, just equivalence and a good `hash`.

As it happens, it is really easy to write a `<` if you have access to `<tuple>`.

```
struct Address {
  long m_IPv4Address;
  bool isTCP;
  bool operator< (const Address& o) const {
    return
      std::tie( m_IPv4Address, isTCP )
      < std::tie( o.m_IPv4Address, o.isTCP );
  }
};
```

which uses `std::tie` defined in `<tuple>` to generate a proper `<` for you.  `std::tie` takes a bunch of data, and generates a `tuple` of references, which has a good `<` already defined.

---

<sup>1</sup> For pointers, it uses some comparison that is compatible with `<` where `<` behaviour is specified, and behaves well when `<` does not.  This only really matters on segmented memory model and other obscure architectures.

Comment: The std::tie trick is great, this is the kind of elegant solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Because `std::map` is a **sorted** associative container, it's keys need ordering.

An `==` operator would not allow to order multiple keys

You might be looking for `std::unordered_map` , which work has a hashtable. You can specify your own hash and equality operator functions :

```
explicit unordered_map( size_type bucket_count,
                    const Hash& hash = Hash(),
                    const KeyEqual& equal = KeyEqual(),
                    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Comment: Is same thing true for `unordered_map`?

Comment: @iammilind: No, that uses a hash function and an equality comparison.

Comment: @iammilind : no, an unordered_map is like a hashtable, mybe it is what you are looking for ? updated.

Answer (score 2):

With `<` you can order elements. If `a < b` then `a` should be placed before `b` in the collection.

You can also determine if two items are equivalent: if `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` (if neither object is smaller than the other), then they're equivalent.

Those two capabilities are all `std::map` requires. So it just expects its element type to provide an operator `<`.

With `==` you could determine equality, but you wouldn't be able to order elements. So it wouldn't satisfy the requirements of `std::map`.